# Unexpected Number of Weights in tf.keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a question about the predictive power of each feature so I need a way to evaluate how strong each feature is in the final model. My `feature_layer` contains two `indicator_column`s wrapped around `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list`s for categorical data, an `indicator_column` wrapped around a cross between two bucketized numerical columns for latitude/longitude data, and five numeric columns.

I would expect the finished model to have 15 weights: 2 for the latitude and longitude, 5 for the numeric columns, and 5 and 3 for each of the categorical columns using one-hot encoding. However, `len(model.get_weights())[0]` returns 513. I suspect the latitude and longitude have many more weights since a cross between two bucketized columns ends up being a sparse categorical feature with a high enough resolution. However, assuming this is true, I still don't know how to interpret the weights returned by `model.get_weights()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the answer has to do with the `hash_bucket_size` argument in the `crossed_column`. Each of those hashes gets a weight of its own in the final model. The 513 weights were a result of the 13 weights from every other feature and the 500 hashes for the crossed latitude/longitude.

In terms of interpreting the weights, I am under the assumption that the weights of the model remain in the order that I added features to the `feature_layer`.